# Mongo save document with empty objectid reference - error: Invalid ObjectId in JSON

Tags: json, mongodb, go, bson, objectid

I'm working on golang server, connected to mongo.

I have a the following reference structure:

```
type A struct {
    Id   bson.ObjectId    `bson:"_id" json:"id"`
    B    bson.ObjectId    `bson:"b,omitempty" json:"b,omitempty"`
}
```

Thing is, B is not mandatory in A, and when ever I try to save A without B i'm getting an error:

```
"Invalid ObjectId in JSON: null"
```

How can I have this reference be no mandatory?

Comment: Do colons work to seperate tags? I think this should be `json:"b,omitempty"`, and maybe the same for `bson`

Comment: It was a typo and I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with:

```
type A struct {
    Id bson.ObjectId  `bson:"_id" json:"id"`
    B  *bson.ObjectId `bson:"b,omitempty" json:"b,omitempty"`
}
```

Comment: How is the first solution different from my question? maybe it was before I fixed the typo.

Comment: @YoniDabush yes, I post it before you update your question.